# Are there tutorials on using custom URI for VideoView.setVideoURI()?

Tags: android, uri, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

Environment: Android API 16+
Tools: Android Studio 1.5.1

I am working on an app with a VideoView.  I need to be able to pass a custom URI to setVideoURI() so that my app can intercept it and serve up the right data (data originates from different sources and I don't want the rest of the app needing to care about where or how).  The format should be something like content://com.myapp/video/some_custom_values_here

I've read an article or two about setting up a custom ContentProvider, but that seems geared towards a database with CRUD methods and returning a Cursor for query().  But, since I'm streaming video data, I'm not sure that even makes sense.

Can anyone point me to a good article or two on how to do this?

Or recommend a way to do this?  (That includes not only how to setup a provider to parse the various Uris, but more importantly, how to return the data in a way/format that VideoView expects)

Comment: To the person who down voted this question: Would you mind leaving an explanation rather than a drive by down vote?  Is there more info you think I need to provide?  Do you think it is somehow an invalid question?  It's a sincere question on my part.  I haven't found docs on how to do it.  I'm not asking someone to write it for me.  I'm just wanting to know what VideoView is expecting, so I can provide it in a custom way.

Answer (score 0):

The example below I use for loading videos from the phone storage (not SD card) DCIM directory:

```
        String videoName1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/DCIM/" + editText1.getText() + ".mp4";
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoName1));
```

If "myvideo" is entered, the videoName1 String is /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/myvideo.mp4

Comment: No, that will not work for me.  The video source might not be local on the device.